# POST doesn't work fine

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, header

Well I have a problem with my code:

```
if ($_POST) { 
//send confirmation email (or insert into database, etc...) 

if(isset($_POST['del'])) {

    $Link = $_POST['del_link'];

    $query = "UPDATE comentarios SET del = '1' WHERE id = '".$Link."'";
    mysql_query($query) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    //header('Location: http://google.es'); //For debug    
   }    
}

echo '<form name="del" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="del_link" value="'.$rowComen['id'].'" />
<a href="#" onclick="get_form(this).submit(); return false;">Delete</a>
</form>';
```

But when I press the link the web refreshes and that's all...

I had tried with: `header('Location: http://google.es');` But I don't redirect to google...

And I don't know if the problem is in the post or in the query...

Comment: All you have in your form is a hidden field. What are you trying to achieve? Plus `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is for file attachments or uploading (FYI) Plus you have no form element called `form1`

Comment: Well, I'm trying to send to the mysql table that query `"UPDATE comentarios SET del = '1' WHERE id = '22'"` and I edited form1 part... Thanks for you down vote!

Comment: And where is the `get_form()` function ? Also is anything working DB wise?

Comment: Oh! I forget it, but I think that it code works fine, because my web refresh when I submit the form...

Comment: I sense more of the code is needed to be shown to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(isset($_POST['del'])) {
```

You dont seem to have `del` form field. so the code inside this if statement is never executed. i think you are trying to check for del_link. so make it as `if(isset($_POST['del_link'])) {`

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in your browser if it contains the right value? The form as it is will contain the exact value `'.$rowComen['id'].'`, unless a part of the PHP code is missing and the form is actually inside a string..

[edit]

I see. The form's name is 'del', but that name is never sent. Make the name of your submit button 'del', or add another hidden element. Easier still: Just check for the existence of `del_link` instead of `del`:

```
if(isset($_POST['del_link'])) {

    $Link = $_POST['del_link'];
```

Comment: I will vote up you, but you have more reputation... So I will mark as solved the other ans..